# Помогите завернуть код в embedmessage

Tags: c#

Вообщем данная команда выводит сообщение сколько на счету монет я хочу его завернуть в embed message помогите пожалуйста библиотека discord.net

```
  [Command("balance"), Remarks("Shows how many Miunies you have")]
            [Alias("Cash", "Money")]
            public async Task CheckMiunies()
            {
                var builder = new EmbedBuilder() 
                {
                    Color = new Color(255, 0, 247), 
                    Description = "Ваш баланс" 
                };

                var account = _globalUserAccounts.GetById(Context.User.Id);
                await ReplyAsync(GetMiuniesReport(account.Miunies, Context.User.Mention, builder.Build()));

            }

            [Command("balance"), Remarks("Shows how many Miunies the mentioned user has")]
            [Alias("Cash", "Money")]
            public async Task CheckMiuniesOther(IGuildUser target)
            {
                var builder = new EmbedBuilder() 
                {
                    Color = new Color(255, 0, 247),
                    Description = "Команды которыми вы можете пользоваться"
                };

                var account = _globalUserAccounts.GetById(target.Id);
                await ReplyAsync(GetMiuniesReport(account.Miunies, target.Mention, builder.Build()));
            }
```

Comment: Что значит "Завернуть код" ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну не код, а саму команду в embed message

Comment: Понятней не стало

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот смотрите когда ему пишу команду !balance он выводит просто сообщение  @. у вас 251 монет!, я это сообщение хочу завернуть в embed message чтобы потом этот embed Message кастомизировать и сделать приятным для глаза

Comment: Я ведь вам давал ссылки, которые вам должны в этом помочь. По первой, генерируете то, что вам надо, а на 2-й из JSON переводите в код (внизу есть кнопка `Generate code`, жмете и выбираете нужную библиотеку). Ну а так, мне ваш вопрос до сих пор не понятен, вы же используете `EmbedBuilder`, который делает то, что вам надо.